# retrieving data from a database using ajax without requesting every x seconds

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have been reading up on how to use `XMLHTTPRequests` to grab data from a database via **JavaScript**.

However, I have noticed that every single one of these *"tutorials"* use an interval to retrieve data every ***x*** seconds, and it seems like this would be extremely taxing (and **unnecessary**) on the server; especially considering sometimes these queries would return nothing at all.

So, how do websites such as **Facebook** and **Twitter** do it?

Because something like this (I'm using **jQuery** for simplicity):

```
setInterval(function(){ // retrieve data every 5 seconds
    $.ajax({
        url: "datagrab.php",
        success: function(data){
            $("body").append(data);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

... seems a bit over the top; especially if you have a fairly small server (or data cap) that is unable to make requests at that rate.

Cheers.

Comment: Gigantic and powerful servers and clean code

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper doesn't exactly help.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to constantly poll the server for data instead of requesting data when you need it? E.g. Based on user action. If there is a resin for constantly polling you may want to look at using a pushing technique with something like socket.io

Comment: @ryandrewjohnson I guess one reason would be the retrieval of messages.

Comment: If you want to see how they do it you might get some sense if you look at the Network tab within Chrome Developer Tools. Check the filter XHR or WS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using on backed, but if you happen to be using node.js then I definitely recommend having a look at socket.io

Comment: You can use `EventSource` to constantly stream data to browser without using `setInterval`. Parse data, if necessary, for changes from previous data stream, then update UI.

Comment: @ryandrewjohnson unfortunately I use PHP, and Python :(

Comment: @E.Sundin I'll do that now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EventSource` to constantly stream data to browser.

```
const source = new EventSource("data.php");
// note, you can also set custom event handlers for named events
source.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  // do stuff with `e.data`
});
// close event stream
// source.close();
```

```
 <?php 
 header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n"); 
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); 
 // get, do stuf with `$data1`, `$data2`
 echo "data: $data1\n";
 echo "data: $data2\n\n";
```

Comment: Isn't this practically the same (if not worse) than consistently querying the database through and interval?

Comment: See https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/. You can also utilize [`HTTP/2`](https://http2.github.io/)